# This HTTP server I written mostly works, but has an issue with mobile Chrome

Tags: python, linux, http, sockets, web

This web server runs fine for simple web-serving tasks, but it gives me a "broken pipe" error when sending large files to devices with mobile Chrome specifically. The only thing different with mobile Chrome is that it does not send a "Keep-alive" in the header.

I did not try anything. I expected to get a successful connection just like any other browser.

My code

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 80))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            req = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            print(req)
            req = req.split(" ")
            if(req[0] == "GET"):
                try:
                    fname = req[1]
                    if(fname == "/"):
                        fname = "index.html"
                    else:
                        fname = os.path.relpath(os.path.abspath("." + fname))
                    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
                        mtype = mimetypes.guess_type(fname)[0]
                        conn.sendall(f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: {mtype}\n\n".encode('utf-8') + f.read())
                except:
                    conn.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found")
            else:
                print("LOL No!")
                conn.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\n\n")
```

Comment: SO questions should be self-contained.  Off-site links to the code are not acceptable.

Comment: In any scenario, you shouldn't expect a connection to remain open unless the "Connection" header field is populated with "keep-alive". Otherwise, you should assume that the socket will be closed once you respond

Comment: I linked it because I feared that the formatting would be botched and that would detract from the code. I'm using mobile right now.

Comment: @CarterCanedy it closes before I can send the full contents. How do I fix it.

Comment: You should try to chunk the data, which is generally a best-practice when dealing with large data transfers over a socket connection. That's the only thing that I can think of.

Comment: See this on [chunked encoding](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9112.html#chunked.encoding)

Comment: How do I use it in my code? I am using the sendall method, so it will complicate things here to do this.

Comment: Rather than immediately sending all data that you're reading from the file, read smaller pieces of the file and format it according to the chunked encoding specification. The added complexity adds reliability.

Comment: I will definitely do this tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

> This HTTP server I written mostly works, but has an issue with mobile Chrome

Such things typically happens if one is only guessing what the HTTP protocol should look like instead of actually following the standard. Different clients are in a different way tolerant against sending malformed protocol data.

From a short view at your code:

- you use `\n` as line delimiter in the HTTP header instead of `\r\n`
- sometimes (on 404) you don't even send line delimiters and end of header marker at all
- you don't give a length to the body - which is bad style but kind of acceptable since you close the connection immediately after sending the body

Don't believe that HTTP is simple just because it is text based. Instead follow [the actual and fairly complex standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-19).

Comment: I made this in an hour on a weekend a long time ago and I actually forgot about this for a bit! Thanks for your suggestions, and I will try to take them into account.